# Allow access to file URLs

Tags: adobe-acrobat

Adobe Acrobat is asking me to turn on "[Allow access to file URLs](https://chrome://extensions/?id=efaidnbmnnnibpcajpcglclefindmkaj#options-section:%7E:text=Allow%20access%20to%20file%20URLs)" in "My extensions", but I don't know what that function is. Could someone explain to me what it is for in this case? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It merely tells Acrobat that if you click a web link in a PDF, Acrobat is allowed to open that link in your web browser.

There is absolutely *nothing* nefarious or harmful about allowing Acrobat to open links. *However*, users should be aware that any *link in itself* can be nefarious.

Adobe asks users to allow this *specifically* to protect users, even in a minor way. Adobe can't control *where* any link points. So, Adobe created this initial stop measure to make a user aware that a link wants to open in a web browser. It's up to you to determine if the *link itself* is a link you want to open.

Basically, the request is just Adobe's way of making the action of clicking a link in a PDF *known* to the user - rather than blindly opening anything that is clicked.